VLC se cierra cuando intento hacer la conversión de mp3 a mp4 de un video utilizando la línea de comandos c#
El programa que tengo es uno que escucha y revisa una carpeta, si en la carpeta se crea un video, automáticamente mi aplicación transforma ese video en un audio mp3, estoy utilizando la línea de comandos VLC, utilizando el siguiente comando:
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" video ":sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,vcodec=dummy}:std{dst=Audio,access=file}" vlc://quit

Y tambien estoy utilizando C# para ver la carpeta y generar la acción, cuando, se crea el archivo, manda a llamar la siguiente acción:
...
pros.StartInfo.FileName = vlcPath;
pros.StartInfo.Arguments = video + " \":sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,vcodec=dummy}:std{dst=" + audio + ".mp3,access=file}\"";
pros.start();
...

pros es el nombre de mi variable para generar el proceso, al ejecutarlo, abre momentáneamente VLC (Así lo configuré, para que se abriera) y la cierra de golpe, pero no muestra nada. Como nota importante, estoy usando un video de 58 minutos que pesa 2GB aproximadamente para realizar las pruebas, ¿tiene que ver?
Intente crear un bat con el comando y llamarlo desde la terminal usando el video grande y tampoco dio resultados, lo probé tanto en mi aplicación como en la consola ejecutando este bat pero ninguno resulto. ¿Pero si lo pruebo ejecutar el comando completo en la consola, si me funciona, tiene que ver con alguna configuración o requiere hacer otro paso más?

Importante agregar que mensaje de error se muestra,

Aquí tienes un ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981454/c-sharp-extract-mp3-file-from-mp4-file
Copia el código y mete el bloque de código en un try-catch para ver qué fallo te da. Y nos comentas para saber más.

Fijate que eso es lo mas extraño ya que no muestrar error, es como si hiciera bien la acción pero no muestra ningun error ni problema, ya que al ejecutarlo con un .bat tampoco muestra error ni de VLC ni de codigo

¿Estás usando Tasks? Si te da una excepción en una Task o Thread, tienes posibilidades de que se produzca una excepción y no se muestre en el hilo principal.
Sobre todo si usas Task.Run(...)

No uso Task, uso System.Diagnostics.Process, pero tambien coloque el comando de VLC en un archivo .bat y lo corri desde mi consola y tampoco hizo la accion
